# Making global functions to access vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

so I want to make a global function that I can access in every component of mine. So I stumbled upon Vue Plugins. They worked great, till I tried out my use case. I need to use some information from the vuex store in my plugin and return a true or false value.

So this is what I have tried

**plugin.js**

```js
export default {
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$rbac = (method, route) => {
      $store.state.generic.user.routes.some(m => m.method.includes(method) && m.route==route)
    }
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
import plugin from './utils/common/plugin'
...
Vue.use(plugin)
...
```

**component.vue**

```html
<template>
...
   <div v-if="$plug('post', '/project')></div>
...
</template>
```

But I get an error saying "ReferenceError: $store is not defined".

It kind of makes sense that I cannot access the store. The store only gets the value once the user logs in.

**So is there any way I can make a global function that can access the store when it gets values?**

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the reference error because the `$store` variable hasn't been defined anywhere. It's not a local variable, nor is it a function parameter or global variable.

You probably meant to do `this.$store`; also make sure you use `function () {}` syntax and not `() => {}` because you don't want to bind `this`.

```js
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$rbac = function (method, route) {
      this.$store.state.generic.user.routes.some(m => m.method.includes(method) && m.route == route)
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) to do a similar thing instead of a plugin.